# Chain Lua metatables

Tags: lua

I am have a situation where two libraries L,M, are trying to set a metatable for _G (named mL, mM respectively). The only thing in the metatables are __index.

How can I chain these two metatables so that if the __index in one fails it calls the index in the other?

Answer (score 2):

Have one metatable that stores both `mL` and `mM`, and if one returns `nil`, check the other:

```
local metatbl = {}
metatbl.tbls = {mL, mM};
function metatbl.__index(intbl, key)
  for i, mtbl in ipairs(metatbl.tbls) do
    local mmethod = mtbl.__index
    if(type(mmethod) == "function") then
      local ret = mmethod(table, key)
      if ret then return ret end
    else
     if mmethod[key] then return mmethod[key] end
    end
  return nil
  end
end

setmetatable(_G,metatbl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a point where your code can fiddle with `_G`'s metatable itself, after the libraries have mucked about, to fix what L and M did, you can just stick in your own metatable that does the combined search, e.g.:

```
combined_metatable = {
   __index = function (t, k)
                return mL.__index (t, k) or mM.__index (t, k)
             end
}

setmetatable (_G, combined_metatable)
```

That has the advantage of not fiddling with `mL` or `mM` themselves.

If you *don't* have the opportunity to correct things after the fact, you could just modify the `__index` entries of the library metatables to do the combined search:

```
local original_mM_index = mM.__index
local original_mL_index = mL.__index

local function L_then_M_index (t, k)
   return original_mL_index (t, k) or original_mM_index (t, k)
end

mL.__index = L_then_M_index
mM.__index = L_then_M_index
```

[Note that as both library metatables are modified, this will work whichever gets installed last ("winning" the competition).]

Answer (score 1):

Use __metatable to give them a table that isn't actually the metatable or give the library a different setmetatable: that way they can't change your _G metatable.

```
getmetatable(getfenv()).__metatable = function ( o ) return { } end
```

OR

```
local orig_setmetatable = setmetatable
function setmetatable ( ob , mt )
    if ob == getfenv() or ob == _G then
        return ob
    else
        return orig_setmetatable(ob,mt)
    end
end
```

(depending on how the library does things)

If you still want to track the things it does to the metatable; look through mt before the return ob (and if you actually wanted to chain __index lookups; add to a table):

```
local env_indexes = {}
setmetatable(_G,{__index=function(t,k) for i,m in ipairs(env_indexes) do local v=m[k]; if v then return v end end return nil end } )
local orig_setmetatable = setmetatable
function setmetatable ( ob , mt )
    if ob == _G then
        table.insert ( env_indexes , mt.__index )
        return ob
    else
        return orig_setmetatable(ob,mt)
    end
end
```

Otherwise this is very bad practice for libraries to be doing; tell the author not to!